# Sound echo function Python

Tags: python, function, audio, echo, delay

I need to write the function echo, that takes in a filename as and a floating-point value time_delay, which represents a number of seconds.Then, echo should handle the sound, with the original sound being overlaid by a copy of itself shifted forward in time by time_delay.

This is what I have so far:

```
def add_scale_2(L, M, L_scale, M_scale):
""" add_scale_2 has as intput list L and list M and rertuns a new list LC, 
    with a linear sum of the two lists times their scale respectively. LC will use the length of the 
    shortest list
"""       
    if len(L) >= len (M):
        N = len(M)
    else:
        N = len(L)

    LC = [L[i]*L_scale + M[i]*M_scale for i in range(N)]
    return LC
```

And:

```
def echo(filename, time_delay):
    print "Playing filename1 ..."
    play(filename)

    print "Reading in the sound data..."
    samps1, sr = readwav(filename)
    samps2 = [0]*float(samps1*time_delay) + samps1

    print "Computing new sound..."
    newsamps = add_scale_2(samps1, samps2, 0.5, 0.5)
    newsr = sr # no change to the sr

    writewav( newsamps, newsr, "out.wav" )
    print "Playing new sound..."
    play( 'out.wav' )
```

Can someone help me please because I can't figure it out!

```
    samps2 = [0]*int(samps1*time_delay) + samps1
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: What is the question/problem ?

Comment: samps2 = [0]*float(samps1*time_delay) + samps1

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: Please edit your question, and specify where that line (292) is in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line:

```
[0]*float(samps1*time_delay) + samps1
```

tries to multiply a sequence `[0]` by a `float`. Which lead to error `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

You can cast to an int instead:

```
[0]*int(len(samps1)*time_delay) + samps1
```

Comment: samps2 = [0]*int(samps1*time_delay) + samps1
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: Same problem when using int

Comment: `samps1` is also a sequence ... and `time_delay` a float ... Use `samps1*int(time_delay)`

Comment: samps2 = [0]*samps1*int(time_delay) + samps1
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

Comment: Tell me what your code should do or this will take years. I'm not a debugging machine.

Comment: `[0]*int(len(samps1)*time_delay) + samps1` is what I think you are trying to achieve.